# How to format USB stick for car audio system?

Tags: partitioning, usb, filesystem, music-player

**UPDATE:** The pendrive was for my parents. When I got a chance, I got it formatted from a Windows machine at my friend's house. I can't try any suggessions in the comments or answers, because I have left home for college. But I am interested to know why `mkfs` did not work. The pendrive was not recognize by Windows either after doing a `mkfs.vfat`. I will accept an answer which includes why mkfs did not work.

---

I have a working USB stick. I made a Ubuntu installation disk, probably using `dd`. Then after a while, when I reformatted it to use it with my car music system, it is not working. I get this:

```
USB device not recognised
```

I get this error when I try to format it from nautilus:

[image]

But it can be formatted by the below command but does not work with the player:

```
mkfs.vfat -n Musiq /dev/sdc1
```

Another pen drive, which was never formatted by me, works fine.

Here is the output of fdisk -l for the device:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 8004 MB, 8004304896 bytes
212 heads, 46 sectors/track, 1603 cylinders, total 15633408 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x74fdf679

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    15633407     7815680   83  Linux
```

Also [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11946533/) is the output of fdisk -l for the working pen drive.

The partition table is `msdos`. I strongly believe that I am not correctly formatting/partitioning the stick.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the Disks utility or Gparted?  Also, your working pen drive is formatted fat32, non-working shows Linux.  You may want to format as fat32.

Answer (score 3):

try to format the pen drive as `FAT32` using `disk` utility in Ubuntu. search for disk in dash.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the partition type in the partition table. It is still Linux as it's shown by `fdisk`.

I could reproduce same thing here. I used `gparted` to create an Ext4 partition. Then `mkfs.vfat` to format it. It does format it but it leave its type as Linux in the table.

- You may `gnome-disks` as mentioned by minion91, it could make only Fat32.
- `gparted` support both Fat16/Fat32.
- Manually:

  1. Run `fdisk /dev/sdc1`, <kbd>t</kbd> change type to `e` then <kbd>w</kbd> to rewrite the table.
  2. Then format it:

     ```
     mkfs.fat -F16 -n Musiq /dev/sdc1
     ```

Order Doesn't matter but replug it if partition size changed.

Answer (score 0):

use parted command on linux if you don't have it just download it!


so run the command below:

```
parted /dev/sdx
mklabel msdos
q
```

and then partition it by running the command:

```
fdisk /dev/sdx
n
then chose as you like for the configuration and then type:
t
then select the partition you just created for example we gonna chose 1
then type "0c" because we gonna change the type from linux to fat32 LBA
then type w
```

done your problem solved ezezezez 

edit:

so basicly the problem was when creating the partition with fdisk or even cfdisk change the type from "linux" to w95 fat32

done your problem solved again ezezezez